# $forceUpdate (or similar) in vue3 - How implement it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue component. This component has a computed prop & a watch:

```js
const resetComponent = computed(()=>{
   return store.state.filtros.room_amount
})

watch(resetComponent, () => {
   if(resetComponent.value.compare == '>' && resetComponent.value.valor == '' ){
       console.log('RESET COMPONENT')
   }
})
```

My `console.log('RESET COMPONENT')` runs correctly, when it should.
But instead, i want re-render all my component, that is, return to its initial state. There's some way?

This is my full component

```html
<template>
  <FiltroCantidad :data="data" />
</template>

<script>
import SelectButton from "primevue/selectbutton";
import FiltroCantidad from "../utils/FiltroCantidad.vue";
import { computed, ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

export default {
  setup(props, context) {
    const store = useStore()
    const data = ref({
      label: "Ambientes",
      value: "room_amount",
      action: "roomAmountAction",
    });
    
    const resetComponent = computed(()=>{
      return store.state.filtros.room_amount
    })

    watch(resetComponent, () => {
       if(resetComponent.value.compare == '>' && resetComponent.value.valor == '' ){
         console.log('RESET COMPONENT')
       }
    })

    return { data, resetComponent };
  },
  components: {
    SelectButton,
    FiltroCantidad,
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to re-render the component is to apply a [`key` attribute](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/special-attributes.html#key) that changes:

```html
<FiltroCantidad :data="data" :key="myKey" />
```

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    //...

    const myKey = ref(0)

    watch(resetComponent, () => {
      if(/* need to reset */) {
        myKey.value++
      }
    })

    return { myKey }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with <script setup>. Does anybody know why?

Comment: @degergio It should work. Can you share a link to a reproduction of this not working in `<script setup>`?